# Wine making folders in home directory

Tags: wine, home-directory, winetricks

So I am noticing that Wine is making folders in my home directory, I know that winetricks sandbox prevents making symlinks and stuff like that, but my save folders are in those folders, how do I make it so that it can still access those folders? 
[image: Those 2 folders]